# MVC - Data between ajax and controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am sending id value by using ajax to controller but nothing appears on the browser.

Ajax Part

```
$(function () {
    $("#personelEdit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Gorev/GorevPersonel/",
            data: "{'id': '@{@Model.ID}'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessYekiler,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
function OnSuccessYekiler(response) {
    if (response.d != "False") {
        eval(response.d);
    }
}
```

Controller Part

```
[HttpPost]
    public string GorevPersonel(string id)
    {
        if (id.Equals(null)) { return ""; }
        else 
        {
            string retval = "";
            string choval = "$('#s2_multi_value').val([{0}]).trigger('change');";
            int gorevID = Int32.Parse(id);
            int[] personeller = (from x in db.OrgPersonelGorevler
                                    where x.GorevId == gorevID
                                    select x.OrgPersonel.ID).ToArray();

            foreach (var item in personeller)
            {
                retval += "'" + item + "',";
            }
            retval = string.Format(choval, retval.Substring(0, retval.Length - 1));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retval))
                retval = "False";
            return retval;
        }
    }
```

And `retval` equals to `$('#s2_multi_value').val(['6','7']).trigger('change');`. Controller returns retval but nothing appears.

This is the part of where I want to see the result

```
 <select name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.GorevlendirilenPersoneller)" id="s2_multi_value" class="form-control" multiple>
   <option value=""></option>
   <optgroup label="Personeller">
   @Html.Action("_PersonelleriGetir", "Ortak");
   </optgroup>
 </select>
```

Additionally, I tried to input `$('#s2_multi_value').val(['6','7']).trigger('change');` code by using firebug and it worked.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Were you successful to return any value from `GorevPersonel` method?

Comment: I don't think that jQuery ajax has an event 'failure', maybe you've ment 'error'?

Comment: No error appears on the firebug console.
Yes, return retval; is working.

Comment: Also, I think that your should change this `success: OnSuccessYekiler` to `success: function(response) { OnSuccessYekiler(response); }`

Comment: I changed what you said but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. You subscribe 'failure' event that doesn't exist in jQuery. Try to change it to 'error'.
2. You are using `@{@Model.ID}` in your data parameter, it doesn't return anything. Try to change it to `@(Model.ID)`
3. here `if (id.Equals(null)) { return ""; }` - if id is null then you will get System.NullReferenceException becaues you are trying to call method on null reference. Try to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead.

Comment: @{@Model.ID} returns the right value it is working and Controller takes id value correctly.

Comment: I changed failure to error and alert worked and said to me "undefined". What do you suggest me to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and would like to share with you.

I changed my controller part like below

```
    public ActionResult GorevPersonel(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) { return RedirectToAction("Index","Gorev"); }
        else 
        {
            string retval = "";
            string choval = "$('#s2_multi_value').val([{0}]).trigger('change');";
            int gorevID = Int32.Parse(id);
            int[] personeller = (from x in db.OrgPersonelGorevler
                                    where x.GorevId == gorevID
                                    select x.OrgPersonel.ID).ToArray();

            foreach (var item in personeller)
            {
                retval += "'" + item + "',";
            }
            retval = string.Format(choval, retval.Substring(0, retval.Length - 1));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retval))
                retval = "False";
            return Json(retval, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I changed the ajax part like below

```
$(function () {
    $("#personelEdit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Gorev/GorevPersonel/",
            data: "{'id': '@(Model.ID)'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessYekiler,
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
function OnSuccessYekiler(response) {
    if (response.d != "False") {
        eval(response);
    }
}
```

AND it is working now. Thank you everyone who tried to help me.